# A Curiosity: What is DispatchQ?

Tags: functions, replacement, undocumented, autocomplete

As shown below, my autofill in *Mathematica* showed an interesting function: `DispatchQ`. Yet, it does not appear in the *Mathematica* Documentation Center, a search for DispatchQ on the Mathematica Stack Exchange comes up with nothing, and even a Google search for "DispatchQ" reveals nothing I can see relating to *Mathematica* (though there is a link to a 1915 document from the New York Supreme Court).

Does anyone know what it is and why it isn't documented?

[image]

Comment: Returns `True` if applied to a `Dispatch` object.

Comment: @ciao Thanks. Do you know why it isn't documented?

Comment: I presume it just falls into the group of internally used utility functions - there's a lot of undocumented stuff. Beats me on the details, and the usual cautions about using undocumented stuff applies (it may disappear, etc).

Comment: @ciao Do you know if undocumented functions usually come up on the auto fill? I don’t recall seeing that before.

Comment: I guess it's an internal function used by `/.` for distinguishing rule lists and `Dispatch`es.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen other undocumented internals show up in auto-complete, and certainly when context is added, for example `Developer`PackedArrayQ` is a test used often by many that shows up.